# Running multiple Typescript 'tsc' commands

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to build an NPM command which will transpile two Typescript projects that are contained in sub directories in my application and the start my server.

I have a public folder called 'src' which contains two folders, Server and Client. There are tsconfig.json files in both as they use different module systems.

I am trying to write a command in npm which will transpile both of these Typescript roots before starting the server ut can't figure out how to so it. I wuold have thought it was something similar to this if it was possible?

```
tsc /src/Server/*.ts && tsc /src/Client/*.ts && node /src/Server/server
```

Here are my two tsconfig.json files:

in /src/Server

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and in /src/Client

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!  You can absolutely do that.  I created an example repo here to demonstrate.

https://github.com/NickolasAcosta/typescript-multiproject

To make it work:

```
npm install
npm start
```

It uses the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package from npm to run multiple tasks.

Given this project structure:

```
root
- src
  - project1
    - foo.ts
    - tsconfig.json

  - project2
    - bar.ts
    - tsconfig.json
```

In package.json:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-multiproject",
  "description": "compile multiple typescript sites with one npm script",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc1\" \"npm run tsc2\"",
    "tsc2": "tsc -p src/project1",
    "tsc1": "tsc -p src/project2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "concurrently": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```